# "num_pixels" gives keyError for regionprops_table in scikit-image as property

Tags: python, scikit-image, keyerror

```
import skimage
import numpy as np
array = np.array(([1,1],[1,0]))
skimage.measure.regionprops_table(array, properties=("num_pixels", "area_filled"))
```

gives keyError for "num_pixels", even though it [should be available as property](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops:%7E:text=attributes%20or%20keys%3A-,num_pixelsint,-Number%20of%20foreground). Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not you, it's indeed a bug:

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/7038

It was fixed [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/7039) but the fix is not yet released.

Until it's released, if you are brave, you can modify your copy of the `skimage/measure/_regionprops.py` file to match the fix.

Alternatively, as a workaround, you can use a custom property:

```py
def num_pixels(binary_image):
    return np.sum(binary_image.astype(int))

table = skimage.measure.regionprops_table(
        array,
        properties=("area_filled",),
        extra_properties=(num_pixels,),
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to fix it within the .py file, it was just two lines. The function is defined there but is just missing in two dicts with properties.